# How to properly increment initialized variables in Java?

Tags: java, variables, initialization

In my dataset, I've got a mixture of ongoing and completed projects. I want to make it so that each time "Ongoing" is found, the variable "ongoing" increases by 1, and the same for "Completed". However, I had to initialize these variables, so I made them 0. Now, they stay zero, even though they're supposed to increase by 1.

```
public static void regions(String pRegion) { // variable region is out of scope; passed into variable pRegion 
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userCh;
    Project projectProvince = new Project();
    System.out.println("Please make a choice from the statistics below for "+pRegion+".");
    
    System.out.println("1 > Number of projects\n2 > Percentage of all projects located in this province/territory\n3 > Total number and percentage of ongoing projects\n"
            + "4 Total number and percentage of completed projects\n5 > All of the above statistics\n00 > Return to main menu\n");
    userCh = input.nextInt();
    
    int howManyProvince = countItemsForProvince(pRegion);
    double percentageProvince = ((double)howManyProvince/(double)linesInFileCount)*100;
    
    int ongoing = 0;
    int completed = 0;
    if (projectProvince.getStage().equals("Ongoing")) {     
        ongoing++;
    }
    else if (projectProvince.getStage().equals("Completed")) {
        completed++;
    }
    
    switch (userCh) {
    case 1: 
        System.out.println("Number of projects: "+howManyProvince);
        break;
    case 2:     
        System.out.println("Percentage of all projects in "+pRegion+": " +percentageProvince+"%");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Number of ongoing projects: "+ongoing);
        System.out.println("Percentage of ongoing projects: "+ongoing/howManyProvince);
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("Number of ongoing projects: "+completed);
        System.out.println("Percentage of ongoing projects: "+completed/howManyProvince);
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("Number of projects: "+howManyProvince+"\n");
        System.out.println("Percentage of all projects in "+pRegion+": " +percentageProvince+"%\n");
        System.out.println("Number of ongoing projects: "+ongoing);
        System.out.println("Percentage of ongoing projects: "+ongoing/howManyProvince+"\n");
        System.out.println("Number of ongoing projects: "+completed);
        System.out.println("Percentage of ongoing projects: "+completed/howManyProvince+"\n");
        break;
    }
    
    
//  int ongoingCountForRegion = countItemsForProvinceAtStage(pRegion,"Ongoing");
//  
//    int howManyProvince = countItemsForProvince(pRegion);
//    System.out.println(howManyProvince);
//    
    input.close();
}
```

I tried to 'return' the variables, but I couldn't, because the method is void. I also tried to place the initialized variables within the if-else block itself, but it didn't work, because I use these variables in a switch case immediately after

Comment: Can you share the complete method?

Comment: @Mureinik yup put it in just now.

Comment: "Ongoing" /"Completed" would definitely be improved by making them `enum`s.  You need to check your expectations, and/or do `if (projectProvince.getStage().equalsIgnoreCase("Ongoing"))`

Comment: @g00se I looked them up and they do look effective, but since we haven't covered them in our uni course just yet, we aren't allowed to use them for this assignment.

Comment: @efx, if they are staying at `0`, then the `if` conditional-statements are not evaluating as `true`.  Are you positive the return value of either is that exact text; `equals` is case-sensative.

Comment: @efx, I recommend placing a breakpoint on the first `if` statement, and using a debugging process to derive the value from the `getStage` method.

Comment: btw I note the field `PROJECT_STAGE_EN` is missing even from one of the sample data lines you've already posted in your other question

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the increment of yours,
but many other places can be improved.
You can split a method into multiple ones,
and polish them, to decrease code complexity,
and improve maintainability. Like this way:

```
void printHelp() {
  final var help = """
      1 > Number of projects
      2 > Percentage of all projects located in this province/territory
      3 > Total number and percentage of ongoing projects
      4 > Total number and percentage of completed projects
      5 > All of the above statistics
      0 > Return to main menu
      """;
  System.out.println(help);
}

void interactWithRegions(String projectRegion) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  showProjectDetails(input);
  input.close();
}
```

And if you need to return two numbers from a method,
you can either use List or an array: int[].
And don't hesitate to use whole names for your variables,
'userChoice' is better than 'userCh'.